# Lorentz transform causes Faster than light motion for Spacelike-separated object?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, inertial-frames, velocity, faster-than-light

Consider a 5-meter rod which exists on the x-axis of a frame of reference:

[image]

Now consider an observer moving at a velocity $0.1c$ relative to this reference frame, from right to left. Their frame of reference will have the new $(x', t')$ coordinates. For this observer, we can make a table of what the points of the rod will look like after the Lorentz transformation:

$$(x = 0, t = 0) \rightarrow (x' = 0, t' = 0)$$
$$(x = 1, t = 0) \rightarrow (x' = \gamma, t' = \gamma \frac{0.1}{c})$$
$$(x = 2, t = 0) \rightarrow (x' = 2 \gamma, t' = \gamma \frac{0.2}{c})$$
$$\vdots$$
$$(x = 5, t = 0) \rightarrow (x' = 5 \gamma, t' = \gamma \frac{0.5}{c})$$

[image]

Clearly after the Lorentz transformation, the rod has a slope of:

$$\frac{dt'}{dx'} = \frac{\gamma * 0.5/c - 0}{5\gamma - 0} = \frac{0.1}{c}$$

which means that it has a velocity of 10 times the speed of light!

$$\frac{dx'}{dt'} = 10c$$

Does this mean that the Rod (a spacelike separated object) is travelling faster than the speed of light? Does it mean that extended objects formed by spacelike-separated points cannot exist, because they travel faster than the speed of light?

Answer (score 3):

It's worse than that, and you don't even need relativity to see why!

Your first two points are $(x=0,t=0)$ and $(x=1,t=0)$.  So $dx/dt=1/0$, which is infinite.

In other words, a stationary rod has infinite velocity in its own reference frame!

Think about where this argument goes wrong, and you'll have the answer to your question.

Comment: Hi! I have thought about this, and how it clashes with my definitions of what "motion" is. In my definition, motion is just when the worldline of an object passes through atleast two different positions at two different times. Now, because the stationary rod doesn't exist at two different times in its own reference frame, it's not in motion. But because in the moving observer's reference frame, it's worldline passes through two different points at two different times, it is in motion. Am I wrong?

Comment: A rod does not have a world**line**, it has a world**surface**.   Each **point** on the rod has  a worldline.  The "velocity of the rod" refers to the velocity of any given point on the rod (as long as the rod is rigid, it doesn't matter which point you pick).  That velocity in turn is given by the slope of one of those world lines.   Your mistake is to use $x$ as a label for a point on the rod and then to use the same letter $x$ as a label for the position (as a function of time) of any given point.  Those are entirely different things and they need different names.